# Debugging CSS with multiple CSS files

Tags: html, css

In our application we use Bootstrap and there are multiple CSS files that are used.

Recently, I had a issue where there was a border created around a input box. The border for the CSS for input types were over-ridden in a particular CSS file.

I tried to use the Chrome DEV tools to identify which CSS file that input box was picking (for color) but for some reason it was not identifying the correct CSS files. For borders, shape and size it was mentioning it was inheriting from the parent but it never mentioning which is the parent CSS file.

Is there a better tool which correctly points the CSS that the component is using?

Comment: I find Chrome Dev tools sufficient.  Just make sure when you inspect an element, you go to the side panel to view all the CSS applied to it (it shows both the applied and the overridden ones, including which files they came from)

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a better tool which correctly points the css that the
>   component is using?

[Firebug](https://getfirebug.com) is great & very well developed. But works only in FireFox, which should not be a big deal for your basic CSS debugging purposes. In general there is no one good tool to debug things like this. You will always be jumping around from tool to tool to get things right. It’s just the nature of front-end web development.

But in general, might not have to even touch the parent CSS to deal with this issue. Just target the element in CSS—if it is not already being targeted—and use [`!important`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/cascade.html#important-rules) to force your new setting to override others from parent styles.

> However, for balance, an "!important" declaration (the delimiter token
>   "!" and keyword "important" follow the declaration) takes precedence
>   over a normal declaration. Both author and user style sheets may
>   contain "!important" declarations, and user "!important" rules
>   override author "!important" rules. This CSS feature improves
>   accessibility of documents by giving users with special requirements
>   (large fonts, color combinations, etc.) control over presentation.

Here is an example code that would force `outline: none` to all `input` elements:

```
input {
  outline: none; !important
}
```

You can even add `border: 0px solid;` to the mix as well:

```
input {
  border: 0px solid; !important
  outline: none; !important
}
```

Comment: Not only Firebug, but I also personally find Firefox devtools to be much easier and more intuitive to use than Chrome devtools.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use the Chrome DEV tools to identify which CSS file that input box was picking (for color) but for some reason it was not identifying the correct CSS files. For borders, shape and size it was mentioning it was inheriting from the parent but it never mentioning which is the parent CSS file.

In general Chrome Developer Tools shows exactly which .css-files are used and from which element the styles are inherited.

Can you maybe provide an example with your exact problem?

[image]

Comment: Sorry I can't make comments yet. :/

Comment: It is an answer actually.  Demonstrating why chrome dev tools shows exactly what the OP is looking for and asking if there is a reason why this is not enough to meet the needs

Comment: @morkro: I had a issue last week that got fixed with help of a senior dev..I get this often and I will post the moment I find one