# Unable to remove tooltip css

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a tooltip that gets highlighted when I hover a input button..I have attached the picture below.."Click herer to search the database" is the tooltip message..I need to remove that tooltip as it looks ugly but unable to find the css related to tooltip..THere are too many tooltips css but im not able to locate the exact one...The css when I highlight the tooltip is aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-5"..when I search the code, I don't see it..

tooltip css

```
aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-5"
```

Is there a easy way to locate it...

[image]

```
button, html input[type="button"], input[type="reset"], input[type="submit"] {
}
.searchButton {
    height: 35px;
    width: 33px;
    background: url('../img/searchicon.png') no-repeat scroll 0% 0% #FFE807;
    border-radius: 0px 7px 7px 0px;
    box-shadow: 3px 3px 6px #51575E;
    padding: 3px;
    border: medium none;
}
```

Comment: Edit your post with the relevant HTML and any relevant JavaScript.

Comment: The code is too huge..Not sure which css the tooltip picks...

Comment: get familiar with firebug or chrome devoloper tools, it'll help you with stuff like this at the click of a button

Comment: Is this much different than your other question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24100988/debugging-css-with-multiple-css-files

Comment: Not the css. The HTML where it is located and any JavaScript that might initialize it. Can't help you without information.

Comment: @Wesley::Exactly its the problem related to the post...

Comment: All: I have added the code that firebug shows in css...

Comment: You are asking how to remove it, not style it differently. You need to post the HTML, and any javascript if you instantiate it through JS. BTW: aria-describedby="ui-tooltip-5" is an HTML attribute, not CSS.

Comment: Remove half of the JS, CSS and generated HTML in turn. If problem still there, continue to remove half of the remaining code. If problem disappeared, bring back code and remove half of the remaining code. At the end you've a minimalistic set of code related to your problem that you can post here and way less things to look at.

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't already installed Firefox or google chrome, do so, right click on element you want to find css, click inspect element and on the sidebar you will find what css overrides other css and in what file and line.